# Trouble with sqlite3 set_authorizer method

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to use the `Connection.set_authorizer` method to only allow certain DB operations with a connection object.  (The documentation is [here](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.set_authorizer))

I'm using this code to test:

```
import sqlite3 as sqlite

def select_authorizer(sqltype, arg1, arg2, dbname):  
    print("Test")  
    return sqlite.SQLITE_OK  #should allow all operations           

conn = sqlite.connect(":memory:")
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE A (name integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)")
conn.set_authorizer(select_authorizer)
conn.execute("SELECT * FROM A").fetchall() #should still work
```

This gives me a `sqlite3.DatabaseError: not authorized`, without ever printing out "Test".  I'm guessing I may have set up my authorizer wrong, and it's just failing to even call it.  (Though the error message sure doesn't communicate that)  But according to the documentation, this setup looks right.

EDIT: Changed `sqlite.SQLITE_OKAY` to `sqlite.SQLITE_OK`, but since the method doesn't seem to be called at all, not surprisingly that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authorizer callback takes *5* arguments, but yours only accepts four:

> The first argument to the callback signifies what kind of operation is to be authorized. The second and third argument will be arguments or None depending on the first argument. The 4th argument is the name of the database (“main”, “temp”, etc.) if applicable. The 5th argument is the name of the inner-most trigger or view that is responsible for the access attempt or None if this access attempt is directly from input SQL code.

Thus, the signature *should* be:

```
def select_authorizer(sqltype, arg1, arg2, dbname, source):
```

Generally, when testing a callback like that, testing is made easy by using a `*args` wildcard parameter:

```
def select_authorizer(*args):
     print(args)
     return sqlite.SQLITE_OK
```

The above callback prints out:

```
(21, None, None, None, None)
(20, 'A', 'name', 'main', None)
```

when I run your test `SELECT`.

See the [C reference for SQLite `set_authorizer`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/set_authorizer.html) and the [action codes reference](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_alter_table.html) for the various constants used.

Answer (score 1):

Martijn Pieter's answer is correct; I somehow missed that 5th argument when I read that paragraph.

Something I've also found reading through the documentation more closely that would have really helped me figure this out on my own is the line: `sqlite.enable_callback_tracebacks(True)`
This line will cause sqlite to print a traceback for errors that occur within callback functions.