# Getting 'not authorized' error with Python 3.7 and set_authorizer method

Tags: python, sqlite

I have relatively simple code which should prevent from viewing the password in sqlite3 db. Unfortunately it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\VR\add_users.py", line 19, in <module>
    cursor = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM users;')
sqlite3.DatabaseError: not authorized
```

My code:

```
import sqlite3
import os.path

db_file = os.getcwd() + '\\assets\\users.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)

conn.execute('INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?)',
            ('user1', 'pass1', 'user2', 'pass2'))

def authorizer(action, arg1, arg2, db_name, trigger_name):
    #if action == SQLITE_DELETE and arg1 == 'users':
    #   return SQLITE_DENY
    #elif action == SQLITE_READ and arg1 == 'users' and arg2 == 'password':
    #   return SQLITE_IGNORE
    return SQLITE_OK

conn.set_authorizer(authorizer)

cursor = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM users;')
```

It doesn't work even if leave just `return SQLITE_OK` line and everything else commented out. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Changing to `return sqlite3.SQLITE_OK` prints the below when using `def authorizer(*args):` but doesn't work with `def authorizer(action, arg1, arg2, db_name, trigger_name):`

```
(21, None, None, None, None)
(20, 'users', 'username', 'main', None)
(20, 'users', 'password', 'main', None)
(22, 'COMMIT', None, None, None)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a debug statement in the authorizer method, as suggested [in this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12068764/11033290)?

Comment: Do you mean this this `(21, None, None, None, None)`?

Answer (score 1):

`SQLITE_OK` is a sqlite3 constant, therefore it should work if you `return sqlite3.SQLITE_OK`.